# Why not "to stop it being blown away"?

Tags: passive-voice

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hold-down

The sentence is a sample one form LDOCE:

> We had to hold the tent down with rocks to stop it blowing away.

Why not "to stop it being blown away"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason why you can't use your suggestion instead. They mean the same thing.

(Although, in both examples, it would be more common to hear *stop it* ***from*** *blowing away* or *stop it* ***from*** *being blown away*.

Stylistically, one has more of an active voice, while the other is more passive. But they are both grammatically correct.

Comment: So both the active and the passive have the same meaning?

Comment: @ZhangJian Yes. Technically, both sentences use the active voice, because the overall subject is "We had to hold . . ." But I used the term to indicate that "to stop it blowing away" presents a more current, active mood (for that phrase) than does "to stop it being blown away." There is nothing wrong with either—and, here, it is only a very subtle distinction. A more common contrast (and "real" example) is "Bob killed Tom" (active) versus "Tom was killed by Bob" (passive).